# Maven : NoClassDefFoundError Xms256m while running Maven Command

Tags: java, maven, maven-2, maven-3

I get the below exception while running maven command mvn --version

```
mvn --version
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Xms256m
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Xms256m
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
Could not find the main class: Xms256m.  Program will exit.
'cmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

What can be the reason.
I have set the below maven Environment variables

```
M2_HOME
M2
MAVEN_OPTS
```

Comment: Please add your pom and how do you call maven.

Comment: I am installing Maven for now and testing it. There is no project that i have created. .I have installed, set environment variables and firing command.

Comment: Also give us the content of your variables, especially MAVEN_OPTS

Comment: Maybe you forgot a `-` in front of the option, it should be `set MAVEN_OPTS=-Xms256m` not `MAVEN_OPTS=Xms256m`

Comment: @ Jesper: I appreciate..Without even seeing my environment variable you guessed it..:-) Great Broda..If you can post it as an answer i will accept it.

Comment: Hey, I know this is an old thread but just wanted to say thanks for asking the question... I just wasted 2 hours troubleshooting until I ran into this post. I too had a bad param in my MAVEN_OPTS variable.